# Programmatically Printing HTML Document

Tags: vb.net, printing

I need a way to programmatically send a print job to a printer of IP printer.  The document will be in HTML and located locally on the disk.  Language doesn't matter, I just need it to work.  I looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

but I don't know how I would call this function externally.

I'm really not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: The WebBrowser control should be great for this.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan-o said, the WebBrowser control will do the trick.
[Here's the code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/1da25ff0-0b6a-4779-9f73-ea13b8f92bc9/).

Comment: But I need the whole process to the automated.  Call a script, pass it a file path and IP address and it prints.  Could this be adapted to do this?

Comment: I would build a simple EXE (or even a console app if you want to really skinny it down) that accepts a file path as a command line argument and prints the file. The tricky part is sending the print job to a specific IP-based printer. I'm assuming the printer driver will be already installed on the computer on which this EXE will be running. Can that printer be set as the default printer on that computer? If so then you don't have to do anything special. If not, then you will need to tinker with registry settings. You might find this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313723) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. Not EXACTLY what you are looking for, but I think you will find it works, and would be easy enough to implement.

1) WebApp saves the HTML output to PDF file. It then places it in a folder that is named according to what printer you would like to print to.

2) A console app (or windows service) watches the folders, and when it senses a new PDF file, it takes the file and sends it to the printer that has the same name as the host folder.

3) You can then set the printers to duplex, staple, fold, hole punch, whatever you need.